# How to create a simple Parent-Children structure with the plain references?

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker

I want to store a collection of children each holding a reference to its parent.

The following example won't compile ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ec189e7eb28cd0a419494b2a5937295)).

```
struct Parent<'p> {
    children: Vec<Child<'p>>,
}

struct Child<'p> {
    parent: &'p Parent<'p>
}

fn main() {
    let mut parent = Parent {children: vec![]};
    let child = Child{parent: &parent};
    parent.children.push(child);
}
```

Is there a way to create such a cyclic reference without introducing smart pointers but with plain references? Maybe some unsafe can help?

If not, what might a minimal working example look like?

**UPD**: to ensure that the parent won't be dropped while a child is created, let's introduce a special method of `Parent`, but it also won't compile for an obvious reason:

```
impl<'p> Parent<'p> {
    fn add_child(&'p mut self) {
        let child = Child{parent: &self};
        self.children.push(child);
    }
}
```

**UPD2**: what if there may be no "orphan" children and they should always be owned by a parent?

Comment: References are pretty much designed to prevent this- think about what  happens when `Parent` in your example is dropped.

Comment: I understand that, but in my scenario, I also want to somehow ensure that the children are always owned by the parent.

Comment: You need to use an `Rc` or `Arc`- in fact, the example given in [`std::rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) is exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, *this* compiles:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de9612b8b7425f8b1e77e6065d76b193

```
struct Parent {
    children: Vec<Child>,
}

struct Child {
    parent: *const Parent
}

fn main() {
    let mut parent = Parent {children: vec![]};
    let child = Child{parent: &parent as *const Parent};
    parent.children.push(child);
}
```

But then of course to dereference the raw pointer you'll need unsafe blocks:

```rust
let first_child = &parent.children[0];
let the_parent = unsafe { &*first_child.parent};
```

EDIT: Let's add a bit of discussion, though. The above code does, in a very literal sense, what OP is asking for. However, there's certainly some flaws here. Most importantly, it's now up to the programmer using `Parent` and `Child` to ensure that no weird shit happens. If you initialize a child with one parent, and then the parent gets moved, boom, the pointer is now pointing to something it shouldn't be pointing to.

So now the requirement becomes: A child's parent must never be moved; or, if parent does get moved, the parent pointer of each of its children needs to be updated.

So to enforce that, you should probably encapsulate your raw pointer stuff in one way or another; the reason I didn't write about that is that you specifically said "no smart pointers pls" and I feel like anything that helps you enforce the security requirements will be some form of more or less sophisticated smart pointer.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes? This is a valid and safe option as long as the data structure ensures the pointers are always valid. Perhaps the answer should be expanded to explain this and provide an example safe interface? Might also be good to mention why someone would choose to use a `Rc` with weak references (in case our "safe" interface turns out not to uphold the invariants it should).

Comment: Yeah, this isn't about whether or not it's best practice. I don't think I'd ever do this rather than using smart pointers / Rcs...

Comment: To provide a "safe" interface, OP would need to show how they want to use that whole structure.

Comment: @effect while this particular rendition may not exhibit any undefined behavior, trivial changes will introduce errors and the compiler will not be there to protect you. I think its irresponsible to suggest `unsafe` without explaining either why it *is* safe, or documenting what the safety requirements are. But even with those additions, I don't think this could ever be sound since there's no mechanism to stop `parent` from being moved (short of putting it in a `Box::pin`).

Comment: Right. The only way to guarantee some sort of safety would be to put parents and children both behind a specific interface, as part of a larger struct or whatever, to enforce safety requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: [Watch this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIbubw86p0M) - it goes over all the options.

I've found the best solution to this, is to not store the relationships in the parent, but to make them available through a method like `get_child()`:

```rust
struct Parent {
    // Only store the data, the child doesn't need to
    // know who it belongs to at this point
    children: Vec<Data>,
    name: &'static str,
}

impl Parent {
    // Just add child data, you still don't need to
    // know the relationship at this point
    fn add_child(&mut self, name: &'static str) {
        let child = Data{name};
        self.children.push(child);
    }

    // OK, now you can get a child, which knows who it's parent is
    // Note that while the result of this function exists, the parent
    // must be immutable
    fn get_child<'a>(&'a self, idx: usize) -> Child<'a> {
        Child{parent: self, data: &self.children[idx]}
    }
}

// Just the inside data of the child, what the parent actually owns
struct Data {
    name: &'static str
}

// This child knows who his parent is and keeps a
// reference to the parent and his data.
// While he exists, the parent cannot be changed
struct Child<'p> {
    parent: &'p Parent,
    data: &'p Data,
}

fn main() {
    let mut parent = Parent {children: vec![], name: "Robert"};
    parent.add_child("Bob");
    let bob = parent.get_child(0);
    println!("Got Child: {}, child of {}", bob.data.name, bob.parent.name);

    // The borrow checker is smart, and allows modification of the parent
    // as long as you never touch bob again
    parent.add_child("Lucas");
    let lucas = parent.get_child(1);
    println!("Got Child: {}, child of {}", lucas.data.name, lucas.parent.name);
    
    // If you uncomment this code, it'll fail, to prevent the situation:
    // 1. You hold a reference to bob at memory address 1234
    // 2. You've called add_child() above; this may have caused the
    //    vec to resize (realloc()) and move all the elements around
    // 3. Now your bob reference is invalid because the vec moved it to 1212
    //    After calling get_mem/realloc
    //println!("Got Child: {}, child of {}", bob.data.name, bob.parent.name);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=731ab0fcad708964792f4b30e3aef2da)